# Problems with authentication with Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to login a user with laravel 5. 
Here is my controller

```
public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request){

        $remember = ($request->has('remember'))? true : false;

        $auth = Auth::attempt([
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>$request->password,
            'active'=>true
        ],$remember);

        if($auth){
            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('fail','user not identified');
        }

    }
```

When i enter wrong credentials, everything works fine, but when i enter the right one, i got this error message:

```
ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 110:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Models\User given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\Pedagogia\Admin.pedagogia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php on line 390 and defined
```

I don't see where i did wrong

Comment: How are you referencing the `Auth` class at the top of your controller?

Comment: Yes, i referencing the Auth class at the top of the controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Argument 1 passed
>   to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() **must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\Models\User given.**

The `validateCredentials()` method of the `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` class expects an instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable`, but you are passing it an instance of `App\Models\User`. To put it simply, your user model needs to implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable`  interface to work with Laravels authentication scaffolding.

Your `App\Models\User` model should look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticable as AuthenticableTrait;

class User extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable 
{

}
```

Comment: i did it but i got another error message saying Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable' not found

Comment: Thank you @Jeemusu. I am not seeing that error anymore, still gotta make it work because when i dd the input they are correct but i got dd($aut) false

Comment: dd() your input variables, make sure they are being recieved.

Comment: I sorted it out. Thanks @jeemusu

Answer (score 2):

@Gaetan you are getting this not found error, because you are using the 
    
***use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticable*** 
instead using 
***use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;***

you user model should be like that:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait; 

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable 
{
// your code here
}
```

change ***Authenticable*** with ***Authenticatable***.